# How to refer to the name file as a variable to be later opened with in the program

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, subprocess

my program first opens a blank file to later be parsed.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['gedit'])
proc.wait()
```

then has the user pastes the HTML of a wepage and save it as:

"first_webpage.html"

Later in the code, I've hard-coded it such a way that it opens the file like

```
webHtml = open('first_webpage.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webHtml, 'html.parser')
```

How can I make it so, whatever the user names the file - that's the file that will be used in `webHtml`.

I want to avoid hard coding this because not everyone would want to name the file the same I would imagine.

I was thinking of command-line arguments but not sure if this is the best approach.

Also, the filename the user chooses must end with ".`html`" in order for the bs4 parse to work.

Comment: Where is the `html` coming from?

Comment: That sounds complicated. It sounds like you want gedit to inform you of the name of the file that the user chooses to use (which is probably not a feature of gedit). The alternate way around this would be to monitor a directory and wait for a file to show up...when one does, assume that is the file you are looking for.

Comment: I would think a lower level editor might do weird things like this. Maybe vim.

Comment: @0m3r the html is coming from the user which is copied and pasted into the blank edit file

Comment: @BobbyOcean i know it sounds backwards. I am open to using other editors for this if possible. i just used gedit because its user-friendly. it may be difficult to monitor a directory because i wouldn't know which directory the user is in. but I will look into that way, at face value is sounds very reasonable.

Comment: okay once the user copy the html then let the code save it to file as html while assigning to variable then use it in your soup

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use a sub-process module like pexpect. This allows you to control your sub-process (reading and writing and inserting) while your user interacts with it. Likewise, I would switch over to a terminal editor (or just use the terminal itself). The idea is that the editor needs to write to stdout where the file is being saved, after the user closes. You might have to write a custom function for this. In general, you need to have the sub-process communicate back that the file was saved and where it was saved; and to do this without forcing your user to tell you is going to need a friendly editor.